# Swift - How to update objects in bulk with out iterating over a collection of realm objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have nearly a hundred thousand records in my realmDB and I want to re-calculate a particular property every time the user changes his device timezone based on the other property in the same table.

Example :

```
    class Activity: Object {
        // In UTC received from server
         dynamic var effectiveDate: Date? 
        // Needs to be re-calculated everytime user launches the app based on `effectiveDate`
         dynamic var effectiveDay: Date? 
   }
```

Assumption: I have 100,000 such activity records in my realm table called `Activities`

Also, realm states that applying KVC to a collection is a great way to update objects in bulk without the overhead of iterating over a collection while creating accessors for every item.

In my case instead of setting the same value for every record, I want to re-calculate the `effectiveDay` based on `effectiveDate` property for every record using KVC to avoid the overhead of iterations. Is it possible?

Comment: Let me re-state the question. You have a Results Object of persons and want to set all the persons' planet property to 'Earth'. Question: does each person already have a planet property that is set to something else?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Let's a `Person` hold two properties `dateTime` in UTC and `day`(in current timezone). I want to recalculate the `day` property whenever the user changes his mobile timezone.

Comment: The question and comment is a bit vague. What process would the user use to change their time zone. Do you mean change the time zone in the App or change the time zone iPhone Settings->Date & Time. That leads to an additional question; when the time zone is changed, how is your app notified of that change and what's the purpose of storing the day property separately when it can be easily derived from the dateTime?

Comment: I have updated my question it should give you more insights now. Pls have a look

Comment: It's still very unclear why you would want to or need to do that. Let me restate the question:  Your app has a user and the user has activities. Upon app launch if the user user changed their time zone you want to recalculate effectiveDay based on effectiveDate. It sounds like you're going to present the users activities to them for that day and that would be done via a query and you probably don't need to keep the day property either since they can be easily derived and queried from the Date object - and that will happen automatically if your device is time zone aware.

Comment: I won't be able to disclose my complete requirements here, but irrespective of the timezones and the complete requirements what I am trying to understand here is it possible to re-calculate effectiveDay or not by using kvc. Also, I totally understand that we can be queried by date but still I would the effectiveDay property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer:

> It is not possible without iterating over a collection of realm
>   objects.

## Long answer:

> The realm is a model class based database. It does not support any
>   query (Predicates or Filter mostly used to retrieve data with a specific condition) like SQLite means We can't update all record in a single query by using the `realm`. So answer of your question is pretty
>   straightforward, Without iterating we can not update the value.

**You can improve performance if you want to change the value of some object.**

**Code:**

```
let persons = realm.objects(Person.self).filter("id IN %@", ids)
try! realm.write {
    persons.first?.setValue(true, forKeyPath: "isFirst")
    // set each person's planet property to "Earth"
    persons.setValue("Earth", forKeyPath: "planet")
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's not what you meant but *It does not support any query like SQLite* is not an accurate statement. Realm fully supports query filters as well as Predicates so you can easily query using <, > ==, AND, OR and even IN clauses - it's really quite powerful as filters can be chained and the returned data is actually live - if it changes in the database, it changes in the results your query returned. Check out [Realm Filtering](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering)

Comment: @Jay I totally agree with you but We can't use Predicates or Filter to update the all value into the DB. Correct me if I am wrong!. Predicates and Filter are only used to get record from DB.

Comment: yes, it does read data only. However, all of the data in that set can be changed at one time. I am not sure if that's what the OP is asking for but you can change all objects in a result 'at one time' without iterating.

Comment: I am curious. Your answer states *Without iterating we can not update the value* but that's exactly what your code does - it updates the values without iterating. I posted an answer as well not realizing you had updated yours. Can you take a look and tell me what I am missing? It seems what your comment says and what your code does are not matching up (i.e. right code, incorrect explanation)?

Comment: @Jay Please read the question very carefully again!. He wants to add different value for each record. In this case how you could manage can you please explain.

Comment: I did read carefully: *every time the **user** changes his device timezone*. User would be singular. The question is a bit unclear as they are asking about changing a property based on another property for a **user** but then talking about doing it in bulk which doesn't make sense as each device has one user. So lets see if they can clarify the question.

Comment: @Jay Maybe you are right but as per VIkram question

I have nearly a hundred thousand records in my realmDB and I want to re-calculate a particular property every time the user changes his device timezone based on the other property in the same table.  So basically he wants the bulk update. I totally agree with you, the question is unclear. thanks

Comment: The question remains a bit vague and OP is unwilling to clarify. So good answer to the question at hand.